# Get value from a text file using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, variables, get, text-files

I have a text file which has one value in it, this value is updated over time but that doesn't matter, the thing is I want to get this value from the .txt file using javascript and then when I have gotten this value, I would like to change my current variable value to that new value from the .txt file. Because there is only one value at a time like 1 or 10, it just needs to get the value in the .txt file and not a specific value.

My javascript/html so far:

```
<div class="curVariable">
Cur variable: <span id="curVar"></span>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

var curVar= 1;
document.getElementById("curVar").innerHTML = curVar;

</script>
```

Comment: If the text file is on client side, and you want to read locally, then you should use ajax..

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the file is on the server, use the following jQuery code:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#butt").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url : "helloworld.txt",
            dataType: "text",
            success : function (data) {
                $(".text").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't think it's appropriate to click other people's `#butt`s in the work place :P